# where are site features in sharepoint?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

i want to add ASP.NET pages in sharepoint having the same theme, so i watched this video
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/bb418732.aspx
however, i found that in the video, they added something through site features "sample feature custom application page" which i cant find on mine. on my site features there is only "team collaboration link" and nothing else.
any idea y that? or to reach my main goal which is adding the asp.net page with the sharepoint theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your custom page in a solution containing a feature. By doing that you can easily deploy your page to all front end web servers in the farm.

You can read more about SharePoint solutions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466225.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543214.aspx

But if your new to SharePoint i would recommend you to read Ted Pattisons book "Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0". It contains all you need to know to start building your own solutions.

Its also possible to add a feature without wraping it in a solution, you can do that by creating a folder in %commonprogramfiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\Features\ containing your feature.xml and your custom page.

Comment: Ahmad: you really need to read "Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0" as JMD suggests.